# Sveltekit Form Actions enhance

Tags: javascript, forms, svelte, sveltekit

I have a basic form that I am trying to submit, with no luck.

My main goal is to introduce a modal that has a "Are you sure you would like to submit the form", with a cancel and a submit (external) button that would allow the user pass the details along.

It is a basic form where I'm trying to use form actions to retrieve the values on the backend.

`+page.svelte`

```
<div class="base">
    <form id='myCustomForm' method="POST" action="?/create" use:enhance={createUser}>
        <label>
            Name
            <input type="text" name="name" required />
        </label>
        <label>
            Age
            <input type="number" name="age" required />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="outsideSubmit">
        <button type="submit" form="myCustomForm">Outside Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the server side of things, I have a very basic form using which I'm trying to retrieve the values

`+page.server.ts`

```
async function createAction({ request }){
    const data = await request.formData().then(res => res.json())
    console.log("create:", data)

    return { success: true}
}

export const actions = {
    default: createAction,
    "/create": createAction,
    "create": createAction
} satisfies Actions
```

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "error": {
        "message": "POST method not allowed. No actions exist for this page"
    },
    "status": 405
}
```

Everything is at a root-level, so I don't understand why this is an issue. I have a minimum reproducible example [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/divine-fog-qjv47p)

Also added a `csrf: { checkOrigin: false }` to the `svelte.config.js`

My larger problem is that I am unable to submit the form using the external button. I'm setting the value of the `formId` dynamically. My guess is that it is not able to find the form from the modal. But trying to solve this problem first.

Comment: In your reproduction the file has the wrong name, it needs a `+`. The action property does not have the `/` and you cannot mix named actions with a default one. You also cannot prerender pages with actions, nor does `formData()` return an object that has a `json()` function, it just returns a `FormData` instance.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I fixed the filename and the `formData` object. Outside submit works